# Shouldn't moderators be following SE rules when responding to flags and closing questions?

Tags: discussion

It sure seems like the moderators here don't like to follow the rules for SE and this site in particular when it comes to marking flags as valid or invalid and closing questions. At the very least, there is absolutely no consistency in their decisions.

Questions are supposed to be single questions asking for single answers. Questions are supposed to be on topic for this site and not better suited to other SE sites. Critique requests are not valid here (UX.SE rule specifically in this case).

And when a flag is marked valid, then the item being flagged should be acted upon. Off-topic questions should be closed/migrated/deleted, duplicate questions should be merged, answers that aren't answers should be deleted or turned into comments (as appropriate), etc.

Oh, and flags shouldn't be marked invalid when they are 100% valid just because the moderator "likes" the question.

So why aren't these things being followed on this site?

**EDIT:** Per Jeff - questions that should be addressed:

Off topic questions:

- https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/whats-a-good-free-editor-for-animated-gifs
- https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8715/good-word-for-a-group-of-intellectuals-or-a-group-of-smart-learners
- [Why is SunBurst background so popular and are there any other ones?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8705/why-is-sunburst-background-so-popular-and-are-there-any-other-ones)
- [What makes Silverback a usability program?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5974/silverback-2-0-anyone-using-it)

Not a real question:

- [How can we design for unsophisticated computer users?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7730/what-can-we-learn-from-this-reddit-thread)
- [Redesigning a My Account Page, What kind of navigation is best?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7546/redesigning-a-my-account-page-what-kind-of-navigation-is-best)
- [Designing for children and young readers?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6803/web-design-ideas-and-inspiration-for-a-kids-story-website)
- [How do I determine an appropriate UX design hourly rate for my location?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6016/ux-hourly-rate-in-new-york-city)

And those are just the questions that I've flagged recently that were marked as valid flags but nothing was done with the questions.

Comment: can you provide specific examples (URLs) of the above? I find it easier to process meta discussions when they are accompanied by specific, concrete examples of what the issue is.

Comment: @Jeff - provided examples - I would appreciate your thoughts on these.

Answer (score 8):

Charles,

**Rules**

Just as is the case with all written rules, there's "the letter of the law" and "the spirit of the law". The written form cannot account for all cases and always generalizes things, so there are countless gray areas. This is an inherent problem with the concept of written rules, which even professional judges deal with on a daily basis.

The site, above all, is supposed to be **good**. For a Q&A website, that means that it's supposed to be effective in providing people with answers to their questions. To that end, it should be active, focused and promote good answers and questions. All the mechanisms, principles, rules and recommendations are there to serve that single purpose, and they are secondary to it. So we (I believe that on this particular point I may speak for other mods too) feel that if a question contributes to this website even if it seems to contradict one of the answers in the FAQ, we should allow it. Note that the FAQ is phrased in very wide and cautious terms - "[Questions that are **extremely** off topic, or of **very** low quality, may be removed **at the discretion of the community and moderators**](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion)." (emphasis mine).

**Off-topics**

You will, I hope, agree that UX in general is a very wide and multi-disciplinary field. So, often it can be very hard to decide whether a question is "really" off-topic. I don't think that SE websites are mutually exclusive. I see many questions that I personally would place on GD.SE, but I can see why they would also be relevant on UX. If the activity on such questions shows me that the community also recognizes it as relevant by upvoting and answering it, I don't see the benefit in removing it. I do see the harm in it (it's upsetting for the OP, and it takes down a question that the community is interested in). The best "objective" indication of a question's relevance to the website is the number of flags on it, and questions that are blatantly off-topic invariably produce 2-3 flags. I don't think you'll find many questions with multiple flags that weren't taken down or migrated. That's as opposed to questions which produce one flag and a couple of upvotes and answers. To me, that signals that one specific person perceives is as off-topic while other users don't see a problem with it.

**Flag validity**

> And when a flag is marked valid, then the item being flagged should be acted upon

The answer to this one is going to be much shorter and less philosophic. When a mod handles a flag, there's the button of "no action required". Once pressed, it brings up the following dialog:

[image]

If you feel very strongly about the phrase I quoted, I believe Meta.SO is the place to bring this up.

> Oh, and flags shouldn't be marked invalid when they are 100% valid just because the moderator "likes" the question.

I hope you'll agree that the question of "100% validity" is subjective, and your opinion on it isn't "more right" than anyone else's who's been around for any length of time. As to the mod liking the question - I, personally, do my best to judge by the community reaction as described above and to disregard my personal feelings about the question. I feel it's safe to assume that the other mods do the same.

Comment: Pretty much this. Especially the decision-making that goes on in my head around single flags. I always try to balance things out between the number of people showing appreciation and the people signalling that the question isn't appropriate. Just flagging something doesn't necessarily mean your flag will be treated with more weight than the 10 upvotes the question has already gotten.

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense that you can mark a flag as valid and have it require no further action. If it is valid that the post is off-topic, then that post should be closed as off-topic. Exactly how can you logically say anything else?

Comment: This may be more for @Rahul - And while we're talking about the flag dismissal dialog, exactly how is my saying that "Good word for `a group of intellectuals` or `a group of smart learners`" was off topic and belongs on English.SE "unhelpful or noise". That is a completely accurate flag, even if you think the question should stay on the site. If you were following what was said here, then there's no way that you could have marked that flag as invalid.

Comment: @Vitaly - In at least the case of the question I just mentioned, personal feelings are just about the only reason I can see that the question wasn't closed. It was flagged and several people commented that it belongs on English.SE. @Rahul was the only person I saw that said he thinks it belongs on UX.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung That's why there's a "valid - the flags have merit but no further action is required" option for moderators. I use that one in case I tend to agree with the flag but don't think it has more weight than what has been established thusfar by the community, as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @Rahul - how does that have anything to do with you marking my flag as *invalid* on that question?

Comment: @Rahul - and please, explain your reasoning on this question then: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/is-there-a-way-to-disallow-multiple-votes-from-one-user-without-forcing-authentic - It has 5 upvotes and yet you closed it with no one other than another moderator voting to close. To me it looks like the "community" felt the question was valuable yet you closed it.

Comment: @Rahul - another one with 5 upvotes and the only vote to close was your own: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5691/what-are-the-recurrent-usability-problems-in-web-sites-today Like I said, very inconsistent.

Comment: @Rahul - and with that English question, the *only* person that seemed to think the question belongs on UX is you - there aren't a bunch of upvotes for the question, just a lot of comments that it belongs somewhere else.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung Instead of talking about this in these comments, could you ask a separate meta question to discuss the issues you have with my votes? That way we can track your feedback on those separately.

Comment: @Rahul - What exactly do you want me to ask - these comments question the consistency of following rules (either set by SE or set by the moderators themselves), which is exactly what this meta question is about. I have no problem starting another question, but I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung I think it would be worthwhile to have a separate question talking about those two questions you linked in your comments and a discussion on why certain votes were cast in certain ways. It's a better avenue than doing it in the comments here.

Comment: @Rahul - http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/411/reasoning-behind-closed-questions

Comment: @Charles, regarding the marking of flags as valid and requiring no further action - as I said, this is not the place for it. That is an SE-wide UI. We can discuss its UX logic on the UX site, or its general necessity on SE on Meta.SE, but it has nothing to do with Meta.UX.

Comment: @Charles, concerning the "group of scholars" question, I'd appreciate it if you stuck to the facts. @Rahul wasn't "the only person" who thought that it belonged on UX - in fact, the question had 5 answers and 2 upvotes. Microcopy is an essential part of UX and I deal with similar questions daily. The ["alternatives for Home" question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8811/creative-alternatives-for-word-home-on-a-web-application) is **exactly** the same, yet I don't see you or anyone else flagging it.

Comment: @Vitaly - it still matters how the moderators on *this* site use it. Can you explain why you think it is appropriate to agree that a question is off-topic and still take no action when a question is flagged that way? That's the point here.

Comment: @Vitaly - as for the "group of scholars" question, when my flag was marked invalid, it had 2 answers, zero upvotes and multiple people that said the question was off-topic in the comments. I'd appreciate it if *you* got your facts straight. And the "alternatives for Home" question is admittedly very similar, and I hadn't seen it until you pointed it out. However, I do think that the two questions have differences because of what is being looked for. "Home" is a common user interface element, "group of scholars" is not.

Comment: @Charles Ah, yes, I've been meaning to write that but forgot. I personally think it's a brilliant feature and I remember how happy I was when I first saw it. I could rephrase the phrasing on that button to "I disagree that this question is an obvious off-topic, so I'm not closing it, but I do see what drove the user to flag it as such, so I don't want to decrease his flag weight by dismissing it as noise. Also, if it gets flagged by others too, then I'll probably remove the question, but I'd like to deal with the flag now, rather than wait around". Does this explain the logic?

Comment: @Charles, great, now you've hit the nail on the head. That is precisely the point. You admit that the two questions are very similar, yet one is considered extremely off-topic and the other is ok. Yet I don't accuse you of inconsistency, because there are the tiny nuances that make the difference. The same with the mods. We do our best to adhere to the guidelines, as we interpret them. But no two questions or answers are exactly the same (well, else we merge them), and a 100% consistency in decisions can only be expected if there's a 100% consistency on the cases.

Comment: @Charles The logic I've described (community interest vs. flags) is also not an algorithm, it's a rule of thumb. Sometimes it helps us, and sometimes other things take precedence. Since you’re probably going to ask “what things” – I’ll tell you upfront that it depends on the case. If we had an algorithm that covers all cases, there would be no need for mods. We can’t reverse-engineer each decision a mod has ever made on a flag. Ultimately it’s a question of whether you trust the mod to do a good job or not. If you don’t, you should bring this up on MSO.

Comment: @Vitaly - your reasoning makes sense. I don't agree with it, but it does make sense. Would you care to explain how you think the questions I added to my initial post are not off-topic and/or are real questions? For the off-topic questions, I think it's pretty obvious why they are off-topic. For the "not a real question" questions, it may not be as obvious, but either of us could easily find other questions closed as "not a real question" for the same reasons these should be closed.

Comment: @Charles Sorry, but I'm not going to go there, for three main reasons: 1 - I could explain my own calls, but I won't presume to know what guided Rahul or Patrick in each case. 2 - the votes/flags balance has changed by now and we won't see the situation as the mod saw it at the time the decision was made. But most importantly, 3 - I don't see it ever ending, and I don't wish to develop this kind of debate for each of the 8 questions as well as for any others that will inevitably come up in the process. Sorry, but no.

Comment: @Vitaly - That's exactly what meta is for. We *should* be discussing why a question should be closed or not. And what guided others before doesn't matter. The fact remains that those questions still should be closed. They are no less off-topic now than they were before. I'm asking for your input right now as to why you (a moderator) think those questions should remain open. If you don't have a good reason, then they should be closed.

Comment: @Vitaly - if you aren't willing to answer why you think specific questions should be kept open or closed then you shouldn't be a moderator.

Comment: @Charles, the meta is not for indulging the whims of specific users who abuse the platform. I'm more than willing to explain to each OP why their question was closed, but I won't encourage you to dig up old questions and drag me into pointless discussions about them, the emphasis being on pointless. I believe I've done my modly duty to you with the current answer and discussion. But I want you to be happy, and you want us to stick to SE rules, so I'll stick to the one that says ["most importantly, don't feed the trolls"](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#flagging).

Comment: @Vitaly - I am not abusing the platform. In fact, I *am* using it exactly as intended. Why don't you ask Jeff or anyone else from SE - they will tell you exactly what I have just said here - if people have questions about why a question is closed *or kept open* the place to discuss it is on meta. You don't like it, then stop being a moderator.

Answer (score 3):

I'll repeat what I posted on [your other question](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/reasoning-behind-closed-questions):

1. Moderators don't have the time to go in to great detail when closing. The close reason links to the FAQ which *should* explain why the post was closed. The moderators are **volunteers** so can't always spend more than the minimum amount of time on a question.
2. If you think a question should be closed **vote** for it to be closed and leave a comment as to why yourself. The moderators will see the close vote and comment and *if they agree* will add their vote to yours. I can't speak for the moderators here, but on the sites where I'm a moderator I give more weight to votes and comments than flags from users who have the ability to cast votes.
3. If you think a question shouldn't have been closed **vote** for it to be reopened. As there aren't that many high reputation users here at the moment you might also flag it so the other moderators can review the decision.
4. Moderators don't have the time to go looking for posts to close or reopen. They need your input, and the input of other high reputation users to be able to do their job.

Comment: And if we give them the help to identify questions that should be closed, then they should be closing them.

Comment: Oh, and if the *volunteer* moderators don't have the time to do their job well, then they shouldn't *volunteer* to do it. I don't volunteer to do things that I don't have the time to do, and I'm sure you don't either.

Comment: @Charles - That's why there's more than one. So there's someone around most of the time.

Comment: doesn't change the fact that if any of the moderators *when they are on the site* don't have the time to do the job of a moderator, they shouldn't be moderators.

Answer (score 3):

Off topic questions:

- https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/whats-a-good-free-editor-for-animated-gifs

  > I'd support migrating this to Super User. I agree it seems oddly placed here.
- https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8715/good-word-for-a-group-of-intellectuals-or-a-group-of-smart-learners

  > Already migrated to english.se
- [Why is SunBurst background so popular and are there any other ones?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8705/why-is-sunburst-background-so-popular-and-are-there-any-other-ones)

  > Should just be closed. Could be a tiny bit more defensible if it did more research had provided examples of UIs that use this sunburst effect, rather than a general, "why is the sky blue?" daydream.
- [What makes Silverback a usability program?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5974/silverback-2-0-anyone-using-it)

  > I think this is on topic enough if you read the text of the question.

Not a real question:

- [How can we design for unsophisticated computer users?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7730/what-can-we-learn-from-this-reddit-thread)

  > Needed a better title, but I do think it's broadly on topic here.
- [Redesigning a My Account Page, What kind of navigation is best?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7546/redesigning-a-my-account-page-what-kind-of-navigation-is-best)

  > Basically a "critique my design" question, unless someone is able to generalize it. Seems a bit too localized to me. Should be generalized so it can help others, or closed.
- [Designing for children and young readers?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6803/web-design-ideas-and-inspiration-for-a-kids-story-website)

  > Very close to being generalizable to the case of "designing for children" and "designing for  young readers" so mostly OK.
- [How do I determine an appropriate UX design hourly rate for my location?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6016/ux-hourly-rate-in-new-york-city)

  > Nicely generalizable with a little bit of editing!

There are 1 or 2 where I agree with you, they should be closed outright. But overall we're not doing too badly here (at least from my perspective).

Some of these questions are indeed borderline, but a trend I'm seeing here is that **these questions *can* be whipped into shape by editing them to make them a bit more general**.

So perhaps what you ought to consider doing in the future is contributing some edits -- as in the examples where I edited, above -- to help make the questions better for everyone!

Comment: Regarding the SunBurst Background question - Graphic Design is an integral part of UX, and while this question does belong more naturally on GD, I feel that it is by no means off-topic here. I'm a UX professional and I don't know anything about graphic design, so I was actually bothered by the same question recently, and I was glad when someone finally put it into words. I added a few examples to the question, hope it makes it more relevant.

Comment: The SunBurst question can be on topic if it wasn't so poorly written. I think a lot of the visual elements we use have different effects on the human psyche. That is part of UX. It's no different from certain word patterns that are popular these days in web copy. (think of product sign up screens, they all look very similar). I'd like to see it opened, but re-worded from a psychology angle.

Comment: @jin isn't that what I said? "these questions can be whipped into shape by editing them to make them a bit more general" feel free to edit away and make it happen :)

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, necessary update to the question is done via Vitaly Mijiritsky. Could it be opened now? I didn't think giving screenshots was so crucial enough for a question to prevent it from getting closed. Next time, I will pay attention to that. Now it is your turn(or that of whomever closed it).

Comment: @comptrol you mean the sunburst question? done